# React component doesn't rerender after state change in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iphone, safari, gatsby

In my React app build in Gatsby I have form with following fragment of code:

```
<label id="politykaModal" onClick={e => this.handleChangeRatio(e)}>
     <button id="politykaModal" name="polityka-prywatnosci" className={this.state.politykaModalError ? "redBorder" : ""}>
           <div id="politykaModal" className={this.state.politykaModal ? "checked" : ""}/>
     </button>
     Accept privacy policy
</label>
```

When the user click on the label, it's suppose to change class of inner div for `.checked` (change background color of inner div). It all works fine in all browsers except for Safari.

Here's my `handleChangeRatio()` method:

```
handleChangeRatio(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let name = e.target.id;

        if(name === "politykaModal") {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                return ({
                    politykaModal: !prevState.politykaModal
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

What's interesting is that state is changing as it should, but the class doesn't (background color of inner div remains the same). Maybe the problem is with re-rendering the component but then why it works fine in other browsers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use the `prevState`, you can just switch between states: Try:

```
    if(name === "politykaModal") {
        this.setState({politykaModal: !this.state.politykalModal)
    }
```